# Using QGIS Server on Windows with nginx

Tags: qgis, windows, qgis-server, nginx

My qgis server intallation works on windows with apache. But I want to use nginx instead of apache.
The problem will be to start the "qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe".
There is a separate server running for php

`..\RunHiddenConsole.exe ..\phpFastCGI\php-cgi.exe  -b 127.0.0.1:9999 -c  ..\phpFastCGI\php.ini`

What do I have to configure to use the "qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe"?